# How to validate entity in Spring Boot console application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot console application that uses Spring Data.

I have a simple jpa repository

```java
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
}
```

and an entity defined like this

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
// ....

@Entity
@Table(schema = "mySchema", name = "myTable")
public class MyEntity {
    // ...
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Min(100)
    private Integer group;
    // ...
}
```

When I save this entity

```java
myRepository.save(myEntity);
```

pom:

```xml
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I expect to see a validation error because `group` is `0` but I don't see any issue and at the database the value of a newly added row is `0`. What else do I need to do to enable validation?

Comment: What validator dependency do you have in your pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to pom did the trick

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `import javax.validation.Valid;` `@Valid`

When the target argument fails to pass the validation, Spring Boot throws a [MethodArgumentNotValidException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html) exception.